# In orbit rocket launch

Tags: aerospace-engineering, rocketry

If fuel is sent into space in bulk using space station as a "Fuel Depot", then how fast and efficient could in orbit launches of objects like probes, etc be? Rockets use huge amounts of fuel just to get above troposphere. If launched "Dry/Empty" and fueled and launched in orbit would it not yield MUCH faster probe velocities?

Comment: I don't see the advantage. Getting the fuel to LEO costs the same whether you do it now or do it later. Parking the fuel for a while at the "fuel depot" doesn't change that equation, and just vastly complicates the mission. And don't forget that cryogenic components have a "shelf life" measured in hours.

Comment: only if the probe carries so much fuel that multiple launches are necessary to put it into orbit

Comment: @jsotola Which is essentially the plan for Starship as a lunar lander.

Comment: That's just staging, with extra steps. The fuel still flies up on a rocket. If we had space elevators or, or could manufacture fuel from asteroids in space, that's another story.